# AppTarget as dependency in Framework iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am a beginner in iOS. In my project I am using a framework for network calls. I have to expose some of my classes to the framework so that I can use them in framework classes. How can I do that? My app has Network framework as a dependency but I need app target's classes in Network framework.

Comment: If your Network framework depends on something in main app - it should be moved to framework. If you think those classes should stay in main app - you will need to design delegate interface for you apps' classes to be able to use them in frameworks' classes.

Comment: @AndrewTomenko Thank you for replying. I will try delegate interface